# Grouping in linq in EF Core

Tags: c#

I have the following data:

**ImagesTable:**

```
Id   Name    CategoryId
1    image1  1 
2    image2  1
```

**CategoryTable:**

```
Id  CategoryName   Description
1   Team Building  TB 2020
```

I am writing a query in linq to get all the category of images and the associated images within each category.

```
var query = from p in _context.ImagesCategory
                            join s in _context.ImagesGallery on p.Id equals s.CategoryId into groupcat
                            from s in groupcat
                            select new CategoryGalleryDto {  Id = p.Id, CategoryName = p.ImageCategory, CategoryDescription = p.ImageDescription, ImagesList = new List<ImageGalleryDto> { new ImageGalleryDto { ImageName = s.ImageName } } };

                var grouping = query.ToLookup(e => e.Id).ToList();
```

My query is returning me three categories despite I have only one category. Please help

**My DTOS**

```
public class CategoryGalleryDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime UploadedDate { get; set; }

    public List<ImageGalleryDto> ImagesList { get; set; }
}

public class ImageGalleryDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: how do you want your result to look like? One category and 2 items inside it?

Comment: A list of categories with a list of images associated within each category